# Create n columns on bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to generate a new table in bigquery using months between two dates (let's say from 2016-01-01 until 2019-05-01)

I know how to generate an array of months, such as

```
  SELECT
    GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2016-01-01', '2019-05-01', INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS months
```

How do I create columns for each of the month generated in the array above?
I want to create a counter month by month, having months as columns

Comment: before you go this direction - think of how then you will be using such table  - what kind of query you will be writing. obviously my point - revisit your design before you got too far! just have `month`, `counter` as a columns (as well as whatever else you need there) and you will be good! this is much more flexible and simple schema that allows to do most if not all kinds of further analytics, etc.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant there will be "databaseName" column. Therefore, I need the following columns {databaseName, month_1, month_2, ... , month_n }. For each month, the value will a counter associated to the given database

Comment: that is what I meant by `whatever else you need there`. so my recommendation for your schema is just three columns `database`, `month`, `counter`

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant in that case the same database will be repeated many times. Also, I have some other info associated to a database (such as creationDate, owner ... ) which do not change over time, hence I would repeat this info as many times as the number of months

Comment: I hope you are familiar with notion of `JOIN`. so you can have database info in separate table and when/if needed - join counters table with info table

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant yes, but I still need to generate a final table in the above-mentioned format. At some point I'll need to transpose months to columns

Comment: this is not necessarily true - usually this is done on client side or using respective tools  - like Google Data Studio for example. Btw this is called pivoting

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant so are you suggesting not to do it at all in bigQuery?

Comment: that is my recommendation